# PHP PDO DELETE BUTTON

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tryed every way but it does not work

> option.php

```
if (isset($_GET['agentsdelete'])) {

$agents_id=$_GET['agents_id'];
$delete=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM agents WHERE agents_id=:agents_id");
$control=$delete->execute(array(
    'agents_id' => $_GET['agents_id']
));

if ($control) {

    Header("Location:agents.php??durum=ok&agents_id=$agents_id");

} else {

    Header("Location:agents.php??durum=no&agents_id=$agents_id");
}
```

this is php script

> index.php

```
  <a href="option.php?agentsdelete=<?php echo $agentget['agents_id'];  ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon icon-left">
            <i class="entypo-cancel"></i>
            Delete
        </a>
```

and this one is index.php where button in

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to ask here, please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and edit your post to phrase it in a way that people can actually help you.

Comment: `$control=$delete->execute(array(
    'agents_id' => $_GET['agents_id']` should be `$control=$delete->execute(array(
    ':agents_id' => $_GET['agents_id']`  careless mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['agentsdelete'])) {

    $agents_id = $_GET['agentsdelete'];



    $delete = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM agents WHERE agents_id= ? ");

    if ($delete->execute(array(
        $agents_id
    ))) {

        Header("Location:agents.php??durum=ok&agents_id=$agents_id");

    } else {

        Header("Location:agents.php??durum=no&agents_id=$agents_id");
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
if (isset($_GET['agentsdelete'])) {

    $agents_id = $_GET['agentsdelete'];
    $delete = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM agents WHERE agents_id= ? ");
    header('location:agents.php');

    $delete-> execute();
}
```

This is enough code, don't make it complicated.
It's very easy.

Comment: That will never work because of `header('location:agents.php');` come before the execute function call.